# Plotly Express Overlay Two Line Graphs

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I know that it is easy to overlay plots using Plotly Go.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_traces([go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[2,1,2]),

                go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[2,1,2]),
                go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,1,2])])

fig.show()
```

However, I would like to accomplish same task using Poltly Express. Is there a way to accomplish such a task in Plotly Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with add_traces

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

data = {'x':[1,2,3], 'y':range(3)}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = {'x':[4,5,6], 'y':range(4,7)}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig1 = px.line(df1, x='x', y='y', color_discrete_sequence=['red'])

fig2 = px.line(df2, x='x', y='y', labels='green', color_discrete_sequence=['green'])

fig1.add_traces(
    list(fig2.select_traces())
)

name = ['red','green']

for i in range(len(fig1.data)):
    fig1.data[i]['name'] = name[i]
    fig1.data[i]['showlegend'] = True
    
fig1.show()
```

[image]

However, I prefer to use go plots, which are easier.

Comment: thanks, but I would like to accomplish this task with only two different dataframes. For example, I have df1 which has blue colors. df2 yellow colows. I would lek to plot them on top of each other.

Comment: @dspractician , you meant both dataframes are plotted in the same graph as  two lines?